# VBA attach pdf based on subject line

Tags: vba, outlook

### Update##

This is what i have got from the suggestions so far. Im lost as all hell...

```
Sub Attach()
    Set objOutlookMgs = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Dim Subject As String
    Subject = Dir("H:\Contracts\Alphabetical\")
    Do While Len(Subject) > 0
        Attachments.Add Subject
        Subject = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

### Original Post

At my work we have contracts saved as pdf's. We send these to people in a stock email template in which the only thing that changes is the subject line and the attachment. The subject line is the same as the file name I am looking to attach.

I would like to create a macro for outlook that uses the subject line to find and attach the file stored in a shared drive.

The file path is H:\Contracts\Alphabetical\x
x signifies letters a-z which are sub folders which contain the files stored based on the first letter of the subject line.

I have a template we use that has a fixed body. I would like to be able to run the macro once i have entered the subject line in the template.
The Subject line follows this format

"Account - ref - DATE"

Format would be something like CompanyName - 12345675 - 23OCT2014.

Is there a way of having the macro search for a file with that name and attach it automatically. 
I can work my way through attaching a set file each time but searching for one i have no idea about.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to make a search for the file, as you know the Folder and file-Name

I think this should work:

```
With objOutlookMsg 
           .Attachments.Add "H:\Contracts\Alphabetical\" & mid(objOutlookMsg.Subject, 1, 1) & "\" &  objOutlookMsg.Subject & ".pdf" '(leave the pdf-part away if this is in the subject-line)
End With
```

I hope this works,
Max

Comment: if you dare to go that way you could search all those "X"-Folders for new pdf's (either checking against a database which have been sent already or just by date newer then..) and create all the mails automatically...

Comment: How do i run this code? inserting a module and running it when i have the template open does not seem to work?

Comment: Possibly Set objOutlookMgs = Application.activeinspector.currentitem if you did not have it. but the suggested method requires the subject to match the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using Dir

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

The main points, not working code.

```
Set objOutlookMsg = application.activeinspector.currentitem

strFolder= "H:\Contracts\Alphabetical\" & left(objOutlookMsg.Subject, 1) & "\"
file = Dir(strFolder & "*.pdf")
   While (file <> "")
      debug.print "found " & file
      Exit Sub ' Assumes there is only one pdf otherwise remove this
    file = Dir
  Wend
```

Instead of debug.print you will want to add attachments.

Edit 2015 02 16

So I know this convoluted idea could work. Max's answer is a lot better.

```
Private Sub Loop_SearchForPdf()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim leftstrFile As String

    Dim x As Integer

    Dim objOutlookMsg As mailitem
    Set objOutlookMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    objOutlookMsg.Save  ' To save the newly entered subject

    strPath = "H:\Contracts\Alphabetical\" & Left(objOutlookMsg.Subject, 1) & "\"
    Debug.Print strPath

    strFile = Dir(strPath)

    Do While strFile <> ""
        x = x + 1

        Debug.Print "x = " & x & "         strfile: " & strFile
        leftstrFile = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
        Debug.Print "          leftstrfile: " & strFile
        Debug.Print "objOutlookMsg.Subject: " & objOutlookMsg.Subject

        If leftstrFile = objOutlookMsg.Subject Then
            objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add strPath & strFile, , 1
            Exit Do
        End If

        strFile = Dir    ' Get next entry.
    Loop

End Sub
```

Edit 2015 02 16 end